# How to add annotation or any other marker to a field during runtime?

Tags: java, reflection

I am creating an object from another one using Java reflection API.
There is an annotation defined on the Class of the source object. However it is not defined on the Class of the target object.

I know it is not possible to dynamically add any annotation at runtime.
Also, there is no possibility of using Javassist because the classes are already by the time.

Is there any way to copy the value of the annotation to the target object during runtime ? It need not be by using annotation.

Comment: You know that it is impossible to add annotation in runtime, but still ask how to do this?

Comment: There might be some other ideas.

Comment: Ideas about what? You clearly ask for impossible. You should restate you problem in a way that it is solvable,

Comment: @talex can you try to answer now ?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy of value of annotation"?

Comment: @talex the attributes of the annotation

Answer (score 0):

According to this post [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params) you should try:

Java7:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Greeter greetings = Greetings.class.getAnnotation(Greeter.class);
        System.out.println("Hello there, " + greetings.greet() + " !!");

        GreeterByHand greetingsByHand = Greetings.class.getAnnotation(GreeterByHand.class);
        System.out.println("Hello there, " + greetingsByHand.greet() + " !!");

        addAnnotationManually(GreeterByHand.class, instanceOfGreeterByHand("Yayy added by hand"), Greetings.class);

        Greeter greetingsAgain = Greetings.class.getAnnotation(Greeter.class);
        System.out.println("Hello there, " + greetingsAgain.greet() + " !!");

        GreeterByHand greetingsByHandAgain = Greetings.class.getAnnotation(GreeterByHand.class);
        System.out.println("Hello there, " + greetingsByHandAgain.greet() + " !!");
    }

    private static void addAnnotationManually(Class<? extends Annotation> targetAnnotation, Annotation annotationInstance, Class<Greetings> targetClass) throws Exception {
        Field annotationsField = Class.class.getDeclaredField("annotations");
        annotationsField.setAccessible(true);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> originalAnnotations = (HashMap<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>) annotationsField.get(targetClass);

        originalAnnotations.put(targetAnnotation, annotationInstance);
    }

    public static GreeterByHand instanceOfGreeterByHand(final String greet) {
        return new GreeterByHand() {
            @Override
            public String greet() {
                return greet;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return GreeterByHand.class;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

(I don't know why you want to do that, i thinks there are some antipattern behind your code)

Greeter:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Greeter {    
    String greet() default "";
}
```

GreeterByHand:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GreeterByHand {
    String greet() default "";
}
```

Greetings:

```
@Greeter(greet="Good morning")
@GreeterByHand
public class Greetings {}
```

Comment: Even I googled and found this post, but dont think it will work.

Comment: Do you understand the code you’ve copied? It’s missing significant parts.

Comment: @Holger you mean that I should add example declaration for `targetClass` for example? I know the code is not copy-paste-able, but if you take a look at the post I linked it gets clear i think

Comment: There is no declaration of `ANNOTATIONS` nor `ANNOTATION_METHOD` in your code. Further, the Java 8 version acquires a `Method` object without using it, while a new variable `annotationData` appears in the subsequent code without a declaration; obviously, there is at least one step missing.

Comment: Okay i understand your problem, i was able to produce the java7 code for this problem, if i'll have time i'll add the java8 solution as well